# How do I download code using SVN/Tortoise from Google Code?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, google-code

I just saw a really cool WPF twitter client that I think is developed by the Herding Code podcast guys [HerdingCode](http://www.herdingcode.com/) called [Witty](http://code.google.com/p/wittytwitter/).  (or at least, I see a lot of those guys using this client).  This project is currently posted up on Google Code.

Many of the projects on Google Code use Subversion as the version control system (including Witty).  Having never used Subversion, I'm not sure what to do to download the code.

On the source page for this project ([google code witty source](http://code.google.com/p/wittytwitter/source/checkout)) it gives the following instruction:

**Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.** 
***svn checkout http://wittytwitter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ wittytwitter-read-only***

I'm confused as to where I am supposed to enter the above command so that I can download the code.

I have installed SVN and Tortoise (which I know almost nothing about).

Thanks for any help or simply pointing me in the right direction.

...Ed (@emcpadden)

Comment: This looks like it does not work in tortoise 1.8 ie no svn checkout option. But there is a cvs checkout option. AND YES, pasting the url wont work :(

Answer (score 100, accepted):

After you install Tortoise (separate SVN client not required), create a new empty folder for the project somewhere and right click it in Windows. There should be an option for `SVN Checkout`. Choosing that option will open a dialog box. Paste the URL you posted above in the first textbox of that dialog box and click "OK".

Comment: The Google Code instruction can be deceiving. They say: "svn checkout http://mock-as3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ mock-as3-read-only". I mistakenly included "mock-as3-read-only" in the URL, thinking that the space is a formatting issue or something. As jodonnell said, only add up until the /trunk, not anything further.

Comment: The Google Code instructions are for the command line only. When executing on the command line, the name at the end is the local folder name the code is checked out to.

Comment: Thanks @Axonn !! Same thing happened to me. I wasted 15 mins trying to figure out why the checkout wasn't working.

Comment: http://replicaisland.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ replicaisland-read-only      URL does not exists

Comment: I was about to waste 15 minutes too, only if I havn't read Axonn's comment.

Answer (score 16):

Create a folder where you want to keep the code, and right click on it.  Choose SVN Checkout... and type http://wittytwitter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk into the URL of repository field.

You can also run

```
svn checkout http://wittytwitter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
```

from the command line in the folder you want to keep it (svn.exe has to be in your path, of course).

Comment: just wanted to include that the command line method is the same for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 12):

See my answer to a very similar question here: [How to download/checkout a project from Google Code in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900786/how-to-download-checkout-a-project-from-google-code-in-windows/5493172#5493172)

In brief: If you don't want to install anything but do want to download an SVN or GIT repository, then you can use this: http://downloadsvn.codeplex.com

Answer (score 7):

Select `Tortoise SVN - > Settings - > NetWork`

Fill the required proxy if any and then check.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the folder you want to download in, and open up `tortoise-svn -> repo-browser`.

Enter in the URL above in the next window.

right click on the `trunk` folder and choose either `checkout` (if you want to update from SVN later) or `export` (if you just want your own copy of that revision).

Answer (score 1):

The manual explains how to checkout code:

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have Tortoise SVN, like I do, take the google link, and ONLY
copy the URL.

Regular-
(svn checkout http://wittytwitter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ wittytwitter-read-only)

Modified to URL-
(http://wittytwitter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ wittytwitter)

Create a folder, right click the empty space.
You can Browse Repo or just download it all via checkout.

I don't know whether you have to be a Google member or not, but
I signed up just in case.
Have fun with the code.

Misanthropy

Answer (score 1):

- [Download the svn binaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613119/svn-client-binaries-for-windows/613147#613147)
- unpack them somewhere and add the `bin` folder to your PATH environment variable
- open a command line console (cmd.exe)
- enter than "svn checkout ...." command there

  - make sure to first `cd` to the place where you want to download (i.e checkout) the projects' code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are behind a firewall you will have to configure the Tortoise client to connect to it. Right click somewhere in your window, select "TortoiseSVN", select "settings", and then select "network" on the left side of the panel. Fill out all the required fields. Good luck.