# svn client binaries for windows

Tags: windows, svn, command-line-tool, binaries

Where are the Windows binaries for the command-line version of SVN? Everywhere I search, it has to be some company's fancy client software with an installer.

I'm working on a machine where I don't have administrator account. Just give me the plain command-line binaries, where the hell are they?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The former direct links don't work, but the subversion project now provides several offsite links to Windows binaries:

http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows

Comment: This no longer works (Subversion moved to Apache, which doesn't release binaries), so this answer should be either fixed or unaccepted.

Comment: Note: used the fifth option Win32svn that provides the zip package!

Answer (score 21):

I use [Slik SVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/). It doesn't require a bunch of registration information like the CollabNet one does.

Comment: I decided not to go with the CollabNet edition for that exact reason.

Comment: But it requires administrator rights because it is an MSI installer.

Comment: The problem is that Slik SVN doesn't include the Apache modules, making it useless for setting up a server.

Answer (score 8):

Get the version from [Slik SVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download/), which doesn't require registration, and you should be able to install it anywhere you want (and have permissions).

If you can't run the installer, you could always try [extracting the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549065/how-to-extract-files-from-msi-package) from it using [UniExtract](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract), or possibly [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) with the [MSI plugin](http://ghisler.fileburst.com/plugins/msi_plugin.zip).

Answer (score 7):

You could always use [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and install the subversion package during install which would make it accessible in command prompt (with some $PATH changes) but I understand if this doesn't fit your criteria of 'just binaries'.

**Edit**: I understand why people are downvoting but it was just a last resort suggestion to getting the binaries for subversion. To answer the question 'why install all of cygwin if you just need subversion': I find that originally being a linux app that I'd be more comfortable using subversion in a *nix environment such as cygwin and could consequently leverage GNU utils such as `find`, `grep`, `bash` etc to perform file based operations, which subversion primarily deals with.

I suggested it because of this and I thought it would be the easiest and quickest way to get subversion as the OP had expressed dismay about finding legitimate binaries: a few clicks and you're done. It was a suggestion that was asked for and in my original comment I had the caveat of installing cygwin right there.

Comment: Why install all of Cygwin if you don't need it for anything else?

Comment: Your edit doesn't matter. With Slik SVN and CollabNet available, installing Cygwin for no other purpose than using SVN isn't a viable suggestion, I'm afraid. It's like buying a new car to fix the CD player in your current one. :-) The quickest way to get Subversion is to download only the client.

Comment: Ah I missed that answer. Thanks :) I didn't feel I deserved the downvotes though. It was just a suggestion and it's not like I told him to format his harddrive :/

Comment: True. You didn't tell him that. :-) You probably would have gotten a lot more downvotes if you had.

Comment: I don't like the answer, but I like your edit explaining it. So I gave u a upvote ;)

Comment: I loathe working with the Windows command shell and install Cygwin almost immediately on a new Windows box, but that's just my preference.  The Cygwin Subversion build doesn't work well in the CMD shell if you have to use it, so you'll likely have to grab something else in that case.

Comment: +1 - using Cygwin is a viable option. Whether you like the suggestion or not is a matter of preference.

Answer (score 6):

I have hust found this: http://alagazam.net/ . This is really the same project as http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/ , which was suggested in another answer.

This is the closest solution to the original, pre-Apache binary. I've been using it without problems for the last two-three years.

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer. It is the only one on this page that is a zip file with binaries, and not an MSI installer, a directory of files that have to be built manually, or a dead link. Almost all MSI installers require admin rights.

Edit: The VisualSVN binaries that bahrep suggested work as well.

Answer (score 4):

http://subversion.tigris.org/

The client-side binaries ship with the source, as well as several other packaged installers.

Answer (score 3):

The Command Line Client from [CollabNet](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/), while it does have an installer for windows, all it asks you is where you want to put the files, and then finish.  Its just the command line client, like it says, nothing else.  Subversion doesn't distribute their own binaries.

> The Subversion project does not
>   officially endorse or maintain any
>   binary packages of the Subversion
>   software. However, volunteers have
>   created binary packages for different
>   distributions and platforms, and as a
>   convenience, we maintain a list of
>   links to them here. If there are any
>   problems with or questions about the
>   different binary packages please send
>   email to the Subversion users mailing
>   list.

Answer (score 3):

I've successfully downloaded the binaries in a zip file and used them on windows w/o administrator access from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/

Comment: As far as I see, there are not zipped binaries there now. MSI only.

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested, take a look at the official [Apache Subversion Binary Packages](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows) page.

If you are looking for zipped binaries of the latest Subversion command-line tools, you can get them at http://www.visualsvn.com/downloads/ (!) without any registration.

Answer (score 0):

Portable binaries can also be found at:

http://www.smartsvn.com/download#svn