# Which svn client to install on Windows 7 machine?

Tags: svn, version-control, command-line, windows-7-x64

I just got a new PC running Windows 7 (64-bit). I'd like to install an SVN client (command line only, I don't want TortoiseSVN). I'm not sure which of these to install:

http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows

does anyone have any opinions on this?

I tried going for the ones hosted by Tigris, but the downloaded zip says to read an install file hosted at their site, but the link is broken. Do we simply download, then call svn.exe as needed, no need for a real 'install'?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/613119/761095

Comment: After reading the answers, I just hopped on my linux server and used it there then downloaded it. This way I didn't have to install anything and the time taken was about as much time or less than it would've been to install (much less when including registering, logging in, and downloading).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use CollabNet's command line client for windows.

http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/

It even has update notifications.

Comment: I suggest SlikSVN, as collab.net requires you to login before downloading .. which is annoying.

Answer (score 18):

**EDIT:** By now TortoiseSVN includes the command-line client as well, if you choose to install it:

[image]

I've been using [SlikSVN](http://sliksvn.com/en/download/) for some time now because the “official” CollabNet-branded command-line client is behind registration and stuff. It's still built from exactly the same sources and shares the same features, bugs, etc. so for all intents and purposes it's the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "behind registration and stuff"? I know that on my previous Win 7 machine I had to get Silk in particular because of some issue I had with Eclipse.

Comment: When I started using SlikSVN the "official" SVN client required registration to get access to the download. Could be that this changed by now. It is annoying, though.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the following choices are equally valid.

[CollabNet](https://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/) (requires registration)

[SlikSVN](https://www.sliksvn.com/en/download)

[TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads/) (optionally installs 32- and 64-bit command line tools and svnserve)

[VisualSVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/downloads/)

[WANdisco](https://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download#windows) (requires registration)

(Source: [Apache Subversion Binary Packages](https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows))

Alternatively, you can install svn with [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/): `choco install svn`, but this is outdated at version 1.8.