# Shell only subversion client on windows

Tags: windows, svn, shell

i'm looking for a subversion client that hasn't a GUI but is accessible only through shell commands. I've installed Tortoise SVN but it adds some items to the context menu of files and folder and i don't want this changes. I hope this is not a duplicated question, but i've looked at a lot of questions about svn clients and i haven't found nothing about a non-graphical one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard Subversion binaries are what you're looking for. They're available from here:

http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows

Good luck!

Comment: No, it's about as easy as can be. The usual caveats apply with making sure it's in your path, but I believe that the installer handles that for you anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You need CollabNet Subversion Command-Line Client [download here](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/)

Comment: As far as I understand the CollabNet requirements, it requires (and will automatilcally install, if missing) Java 1.6 and Python 2.5. I would prefere the old Tigris command line client, which works without this. Unfortunately it is no longer maintained. Does anybody know about a replacment without Java and Python?

Comment: I don't think CollabNet requires neither Java nor Python as long as we are talking about the command line client.

Comment: Confirmed, see for yourself http://www.collab.net/nonav/downloads/subversion/requirements/svn1.6_commandline_client_windows.html

Answer (score 3):

Another option is [SlikSVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download/). I'm not sure what the difference is between SlikSVN and CollabNet, but I've been using SlikSVN from Nant scripts for a couple of years without trouble.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613119/svn-client-binaries-for-windows), the CollabNet installer asks for registration, unlike SlikSVN.

Comment: One small difference is that the Slik Subversion binaries rename all DLLs, to make sure you don't get collisions with other Subversion binaries.

Comment: Funny thing about SlikSVN is that if you look at properties of their svn.exe you'll see on the "Details" tab that the Copyright says CollabNet (at least in my old - 1.6.12 version)

Answer (score 2):

CollabNet Subversion Command-Line Client v1.6.11 (for Windows)

this is what you need.
can be found [here](http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/)