# Question Regarding SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using tortoise SVN to check in, check out etc. The repository is present in a remote location.

How can I run svn commands in command line (windows xp) ?

Comment: Do you want to use the command line, just because the repository is in a remote location?

Comment: No. I am just trying to learn how to use commands :)

Comment: :) Good, start using Linux, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others have said, TortoiseSVN does not come with the standard SVN client ( and here is the reason it doesn't - http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#svnbinaries)

So you need to install a SVN command line client for you to be running SVN commands. You can look at this link for those - http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows.

I myself prefer [SlikSVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download). It lives up to its name. You can also use the [Collabnet](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/) one ( choose CollabNet Subversion Command-Line Client from the link )

It is great that you want to try out with command line as well, since eventhough GUI clients like Tortoise make your life much simpler, it is good to have the basic command line knowledge to understand what is happening and also for that situation where you cannot do something without the command line ( believe me, these situations do occur )

Answer (score 2):

Using Command line SVN under Windows

https://www.forge.funambol.org/scdocs/ddUsingSVN_command-line

It would be easier if you try to use using GUI options for better and faster work.

Answer (score 1):

Tortoise does not install the command-line tools. You have to install it from the [official site](http://subversion.apache.org). Make sure to install compatible version, because the working directory format changes slightly over time. Generally the first two digits of version must match, so if your TortoiseSVN is linked against 1.6.x, you may install 1.6.y, but neither 1.5.z nor 1.7.z.

Answer (score 0):

Tortoise SVN does not come with the SVN command line tools. You could add Visual SVN (which does come with the CLI tools) besides your Tortoise installation and add the binary path to your PATH. Just make sure that the versions match up, otherwise you could get quite irritating issues when trying to commit from one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a command line client, only because the repository is in a remote location. However, if you need a client [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613119/svn-client-binaries-for-windows) explains the details.

Answer (score -2):

Start -> Run... Type **cmd**. 
By doing this you’ll run command line session where you can interact with system by typing commands.

You can then move to your repository folder: **cd** [path to repository]

And continue typing your commands like:

**svn st**,
**svn update**, etc.

Comment: The poster did NOT say he/she installed the CLI tools. They are not included in Tortoise.