# error with Subversion client while using Intellij IDEA

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij IDEA v13.1.5 on Windows (JDK1.7) and Subversion 1.8.  I am getting the following error in Intellij (wondering if I need to downgrade) and if so, what is the best option to do so:

```
**URL**:
svn: E155021: E155021: This client is too old to work with the working copy at 'C:\projectName' (format 31). You need to get a newer Subversion client. For more details, see http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#working-copy-format-change
**Format**:
1.8
**Depth**:
unknown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue went away when I downgraded my svn (tortoise or slick) to v1.6.  IntelliJ did not complain about svn client version after that.  I previously had svn client v1.8 which caused the issue with IntelliJ.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure IntelliJ to use your Command Line SVN client:

[image: screen shot of preferences dialog of IntelliJ: Version Control > Subversion]

Take care to use the path that points to a current installation of SVN on your system. On my OS X, `/usr/bin/svn` was 1.7, while I had a 1.8 installed via homebrew in `/usr/local/bin/svn`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/12/subversion-1-8-and-intellij-idea-13/) subversion 1.8 should be supported in the version 13. Do you have upgraded SVN command line binaries installed ?

Comment: using slicksvn but not working - moving to older version of slicksvn to see if that works out

Comment: so the problem seems due the binaries that intelliJ idea is using.

Comment: yes - which is why I'm moving to older version of slicksvn

Comment: simply  moving to older version of slicksvn did not fix the issue.

Comment: I guess that you would need only the binary command svn [not 100% sure as I am not using SVN for years at this point]. Idea should just use the svn binary command. Have a look at this [svn client binaries for windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613119/svn-client-binaries-for-windows) for possible clients.

Comment: thanks - appreciated.  I have to use both svn ad git since older codebase is in svn (and no one transferred it over to git)