# How to download/checkout a project from Google Code in Windows?

Tags: zip, google-code

How do I download a ZIP file of an entire project from Google Code when there are no prepared downloads available?

This is what I see on the checkout page:

> **Command-line access**
>   Use this command to anonymously check out the latest project source code:

```
svn checkout http://myproject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ myproject-read-only
```

But I'm working on Windows and I don't have the svn binaries ... do I need these?

I can access individual source code file or view the Subversion HTML pages, but that just allows me to access source code files one-by-one.

Comment: Similar to, but NOT a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766/how-do-i-download-code-using-svn-tortoise-from-google-code

Comment: I thought i am the only lazy guy searching for this :), Glad to know i got a big club :P

Comment: Answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386894/download-an-svn-repository include a web interface.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

If you don't want to install anything but do want to download an SVN or GIT repository, then you can use this: http://downloadsvn.codeplex.com/

I have nothing to do with this project, but I just used it now and it saved me a few minutes. Maybe it will help someone.

Comment: @Hanuman: It may be possible to achieve this using that project and Mono: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software). I'm afraid I don't know.

Comment: Almost exactly what I was looking for (and exactly for the asker), except I was looking for a website where I can enter the SVN URL and it will let me download a ZIP of the checked out source. But I guess, a simple app like this can also work just as well.

Comment: The very reason I want this is because I don't seem to be able to use svn behind a proxy on cygwin... having to download an exe which doesn't support (authenticated) proxies doesn't help :/ For whomever this has been useful (which means they're able to run executables and have a decent network connection): just get an svn client and learn to use it. You can thank me later.

Comment: I can't believe you downvoted me for that?! Why not get the source code and then add proxy support yourself? It's a trivial task and downvoting this answer because of it is absurd; it's not my code I'm providing!

Comment: Thanks! .. This is very useful. Does this not have provision to add username password?

Comment: I'd like to add (because this threw me off) but with in this program using this project "svn checkout http://myproject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ myproject-read-only" you would ONLY use "http://myproject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/" as the URL, after the space is just a title and I feel this might be helpful for someone who comes into the same confusion

Answer (score 9):

If you install [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) you can use SVN under windows. It also gives you the SVN binaries. You needn't do the checkout from the command-line though as it integrates into Windows Explorer for you.

Comment: After you install TortoiseSVN in Windows, create a new folder for the project somewhere and right click it. There should be an option for "SVN Checkout". Paste the URL in the first textbox of the dialog box and click "OK".

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to install TortoiseSVN, you can simply install 'Subversion for Windows' from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/

After installing, just open up a command prompt, go the folder you want to download into, then past in the checkout command as indicated on the project's 'source' page.  E.g.

svn checkout http://projectname.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ projectname-read-only

Note the space between the URL and the last string is intentional, the last string is the folder name into which the source will be downloaded.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Mr. Tom Chantler
adding that to get the exe http://downloadsvn.codeplex.com/ to pull the SVN source

just note that suppose you're downloading the below project:
you have to enter exactly the following to donwload it in the exe URL:

http://myproject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

developer not taking care of appending the h t t p : / / if it does not exist.
Hope it saves somebody's time.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple solution without the TortoiseSVN overhead is **[RapidSVN](http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/)**. It is a lightweight open-source SVN client that is easy to install and easy to use.

The [Download SVN](http://downloadsvn.codeplex.com) tool did also work quite well, but it had problems with SVN repositories that don't provide a web interface. RapidSVN works fine with those.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a github account and don't want to download software, you can export to github, then download a zip from github.