# Tortoise svn newbie checkout

Tags: version-control, tortoisesvn

I am new to this version control bussiness and i chose to use tortoise svn 1.8 as a start [downloaded here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisecvs/files/tortoisecvs-stable/TortoiseCVS%201.8.32/TortoiseCVS-1.8.32.exe/download)
.I also created an account with google code and was given these instructions

```
# Project members authenticate over HTTPS to allow committing changes.
svn checkout https://research-and-writers-club.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ research-and-writers-club --username deniswisedeniswise@gmail.com

When prompted, enter your generated googlecode.com password.
```

**The problem**
I want to connect to this account using tortoise as described in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900786/how-to-download-checkout-a-project-from-google-code-in-windows/5493172#5493172) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766/how-do-i-download-code-using-svn-tortoise-from-google-code) but i  dont see a "SVN Checkout" BUT THERE IS "CVS Chechout" and clicking it gives a complicated dialog box and am unsure how to proceed. Please help.(am new to tortoise svn).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You downloaded **TortoiseCVS**, whereas you need **TortoiseSVN**. The former is a CVS client, the latter is a SVN client.

Answer (score 5):

You downloaded Tortoise CVS and not Tortoise SVN.
Install the good one and it will work ;-)

http://tortoisesvn.net/