# Download an SVN repository?

Tags: svn, google-code

I'm looking for an online tool that will allow me downloading an online SVN repository (google code etc.).

Do you know of anything?

**Update**
I want to download the top parent folder and all its subfolders and content, without installing anything on my computer.

Comment: @Almo, I want it to be online, question updated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [An online SVN client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192310/an-online-svn-client)

Comment: I've marked my question for closing. I've found my answer somewhere else. I just didn't know that you call it "SVN Client".

Comment: @Shimmy the "An online SVN client" link has been removed "for reasons of moderation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a GUI to access SVN repos you can use http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ (and its Repobrwoser)
If you want a browser based tool, to browse ANY SVN repo without installing SVn on your machine, i don't such a tool. I know only tools to install to your webserver and needed a installed SVN client on these server.
To checkout or export a svn repo you need a svn client. (or you copy the files from the command line =) )

Comment: Then you must copy these folder per command line, if you have accesses. But then you copy all .svn folder, too.

Comment: I have access, of course, can I do that without installing anything?

Comment: Yes, this are normal Files, so you can copy they by the normal way. But all these .svn folders (in every folder or subfolder svn creates such a folder to store his informations) uses more space than the project files, so an export is the better way.

Comment: https connections are slow on my ISP and i suddenly get "connection closed by server " message. but using eu5, i can finally get the repo i wanted.

Answer (score 144):

If you want to download SVN repository online (e.g. Google Code) without installing anything, you can use wget:

`wget -m -np http://myproject.googlecode.com/svn/myproject/trunk/`

If authorization is required, you can use the `--user` and `--ask-password` flags, which will prompt you for your password:

`wget --user=yourusername --ask-password -m -np http://myproject.googlecode.com/svn/myproject/trunk/`

Explaining what the parameter does:

`-m, --mirror:`

> Turn on options suitable for mirroring.  This option turns on
>   recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and keeps
>   FTP directory listings.  It is currently equivalent to `-r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing`.

`-np, --no-parent:`

> Do not ever ascend to the parent directory when retrieving
>   recursively. This is a useful option, since it guarantees that only
>   the files below a certain hierarchy will be downloaded.

Comment: This didn't work for me, the example here worked though - http://logbuffer.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/get-files-from-svn-via-wget/

Comment: very helpful.  thanks.  i was trying to download from code.google.com a project that did not have a zip download, and this webpage did just that...

Comment: It doesnt work for [quickgraph](http://quickgraph.tigris.org/svn/quickgraph/trunk), returns empty zip.

Comment: @EmperorOrionii Quickgraph repos need a User/Password, the website cannot go through.
The wget version worked for me on another repos.

Comment: Site is down unfortunately, are there any alternatives?

Comment: >> When does it not work?

Sometimes against WebSVN (e.g., v. 2.3.3).  Running this command yields files like:

.project
...
.project@op=rss&peg=20
.project@op=rss&peg=21
...

Comment: Google Chrome tells me that site is phishing.

Comment: totally worked for me. but it did take some time to download a single SVN repo from Google Code (or is itjust my internet connection haha). Thanks!

Comment: This works on `svn.apache.org` too. But the resulting tree has an `index.html` file in every directory. I suspect it's not too friendly to the webserver either. On that server is also MUCH slower than just doing a svn checkout. (I stopped the wget after 15 minutes but the svn checkout took less than a minute.)

Comment: @Eponymous This is for those who don't want to install SVN. You can also remove all _index.html_ files by `find . -name 'index.html' -delete`

Comment: `-np` `--no-parent`::
           Do not ever ascend to the parent directory when retrieving recursively.  This is a useful option, since it guarantees that only the files below a certain hierarchy will be downloaded.

Comment: `-m`  `--mirror` :: Turn on options suitable for mirroring.  This option turns on recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and keeps FTP directory listings.  It is currently equivalent to `-r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing`.

Comment: `If you want to download SVN repository online without installing anything`?  That's just untrue.  `wget` is a third-party program that doesn't come bundled with Windows.  You definitely have to or had to install it.

Comment: This worked great for me on Linux, but is there a Windows (PowerShell) option? There is 'Invoke-WebRequest' which has the alias of 'wget', but they don't function quite the same.

Comment: this didn't work for me b/c my repo had actual index.html files in it that got replaced with html for the directory listing

Comment: This link is useful for me to install and use wget: https://www.jcchouinard.com/wget/

Answer (score 14):

.NET utility for downloading google code project files(SVN). Also has Git support. Requires .Net 2.0

<del>http://downloadsvn.codeplex.com/</del>

**EDIT**
(now located here https://github.com/ststeiger/DownloadSVN)

Comment: +1 for this utility.  Single EXE, needs no install (does need .NET though), worked flawlessly and quickly.

Comment: Great tool. Thank you very much.

Comment: Doesn't seem to support username/password

Answer (score 11):

Install svn, navigate to your directory then run the command `svn checkout <url-to-repostitory> .`.

Please provide us with some details like your operating system and what/where you want to download.

Comment: Well you either have to install SVN or install an SVN tool, you may as well install SVN.

Answer (score 5):

signup to github and then use:

https://import.github.com/new.

instructions:

https://help.github.com/articles/importing-from-subversion/#importing-a-subversion-project-to-git-using-svn2git

once you have a git repo on github you can download zip

Answer (score 3):

One the upper left in Google Code it has a link "Checkout"

Click that and you will get a command line suggestion:

```
Command-line access

Use this command to anonymously check out the latest project source code:

 Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
svn checkout http://yourfolder.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ yourfolder-read-only
```

If you want a subfolder only then add it after trunk

If you are on linux & have SVN installed just CD to the folder where you want it installed first then run the above command - it will download fast

I tried all the other suggestions & this is the only thing that worked, couldnt do it with bazaar or svnDownloader app.

Answer (score 2):

Google page have a link that you can download the source code and the full tree.

Go to the **Source** tab, then click on **Browse**

[image]

then you see the link for Download it as:

[image]

Comment: There is no Download zip | tar.gz link there.

Comment: @Narek I browse a random project and you have right I do not see this download - how ever when I add it and the screen shots are original, I do not know why on some exist and on some other not.

Answer (score 1):

For me DownloadSVN is the best SVN client no install no explore shell integration so no need to worry about system instability small and very light weight and it does a great job just recently i had a very bad experience with TortoiseSVN on my WindowsXP_x86:) luckily i found this great SVN client

Comment: What if there is login required?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about checking it out, you probably want the subversion itself. If you're interested in history, I'd use `git-svn`. If you want the real subversion clone, I don't know, there was something. :)

Comment: on a mac - OSx 10.8.2 - it seems to be $ git svn <command> without the hyphen.

Comment: Yes, I just mentioned the phenomenon. It may work also both ways, but I think on your system `git-svn` binary is not in the path.

Answer (score 0):

If you have proxy i suggest using [SVNGITDownloader](https://github.com/smzahraee/SVNGITDownloader/tree/SvnGit-Downloader) it is under .NET Framework
and its source code is available