# Online service to download a SVN repository / folder?

Tags: svn, download, firewall

I need to access a SVN repository that is available online but unfortunately, I am behind a firewall that will not allow `svn checkout ...` etc. Is there a service that I could give the repository URL, it would download the files for me and provide a ZIP file or something?

Related question: [Download an SVN repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386894/download-an-svn-repository) However, the answers are not helpful for my case (I absolutely cannot use a local SVN client).

Comment: Who hosts the svn repository? Btw this is off topic for SO.

Comment: access svn repository in the same way you want to access the service - Profit.

Comment: One helpfull answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25784639/159270

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since http://svndownload.eu5.org/ does not seem to work any longer, I suggest using `wget` as explained [in an answer to the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349920/299756).

If you are on a Windows machine and need `wget` I can recommend [GOW (Gnu On Windows)](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow) as a lightweight collection of unix commands for windows.

Answer (score 10):

The web [kalyfe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16102481/1099452) tolds didn't worked me, and I ended downloading a corrupted `.zip` file. But if you can browse the code using HTTP(s), you can use [this client app](http://downloadsvn.codeplex.com/).

**Update 2016.03**: testing again the site, our new corporate firewall says that site is malicious.

Answer (score 6):

There is a lightweight tool, for Windows however.

it can download Git and SVN repositories

https://downloadsvn.codeplex.com/

Comment: Very simple and useful tool, does just one thing and does it right :-)

Comment: fyi, this doesn't support svn:externals