# How to download sample code from google code website?

Tags: macos, google-code

I'm looking around this `Google code` [link](http://gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Examples/) from last an hour, can't find a way to download folders of sample code. When I click on any one of the Folder, it will take me inside it, and show all files, after click on any of the file, it will show the content of the file! Instead open it there, I want to download it. How can I download those samples folder? I've Google it and as people talking about SVN and commands to pass with command-line tool, I don't have any knowledge about it, is there any easiest way to get this? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use wget you can use the following command

```
wget -m -np http://gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
```

See the following questions for more info

[Download an SVN repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386894/download-an-svn-repository)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192310/an-online-subversion-client

[How do I download code using SVN/Tortoise from Google Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766/how-do-i-download-code-using-svn-tortoise-from-google-code?rq=1)

Comment: I downloaded wget and install it, then follow the command given in answer. It did all I want. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Linux, you can check the code out by issuing such a command:

```
svn co https://gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
```

Or if you're using Windows, download a SVN client program, such as [Tortoise SVN](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=tortoise%20svn&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CCQQjBAwAQ&url=http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html&ei=-B2SULOdKMyviQelzIGYDw&usg=AFQjCNFmD-Olcg_ZJKVLxjE8XMiL16LhDQ), install it and follow [this guide](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html) to download the code you want. And for MAC OSX, you can use [this guide](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion)

Comment: See question `tag`, I'm using `MAC OSX`.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. : ) Then I guess you may want to download a SVN client for Mac such as [this](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion). The command to check out is not different.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the command:

```
svn checkout http://gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ gdata-objectivec-client-read-only
```

Off course, you will have to install a SVN client first.

Answer (score 1):

As it was said, the right way is to use a subversion client. It´s easy, install it and execute the command svn co http://...

You can also use some tools like wget or any other that allows you to download web files and folders.