# Android notification manager and timepricker

Tags: android, notifications

I am making `NotificationManager`. I have created `datepicker` when notification has to appear.

Next thing I need is time. I have learned everything about `TimePickers`, but can someone show me an example how to set time for `notification`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://code.google.com/p/kraigsandroid/) will help. It's the source code of [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.angrydoughnuts.android.alarmclock) open source app. This is maybe a good example for your notification.

Comment: the source code is also included in my post, the first 'this'

Comment: I can only find all type of apk version files. If you can you should correct your answer with a link where is a code. Not a main page

Comment: And is there any way to download all package?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900786/how-to-download-checkout-a-project-from-google-code-in-windows