# How download a project from code.google?

Tags: java, android

How can i download a project from code.goole.com ?
it gives me a checkout like this :

> http://mensch-aergere-dich-nicht.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
> mensch-aergere-dich-nicht-read-only

i also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900786/how-to-download-checkout-a-project-from-google-code-in-windows) topic and use DownloadSVN but it gives me error :

> Failed to download: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

i already download project without these kinds of probelm :(

tnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that project is not configured correctly. There are no files in the `trunk/` folder. Try downloading

```
http://mensch-aergere-dich-nicht.googlecode.com/svn/MenschAergereDichNicht/
```

(I don't use SVN, so I don't know if that URL will work with `svn checkout` or if you need to download the individual files some other way.)