# Google app engine setup from checkout project from svn

Tags: svn

I am trying to do salesforce Single sign on using google app engine. I am refering this document [Single Sign On](http://code.google.com/p/sfdc-gae-sso-delegated-auth/wiki/Setup#Google_App_Engine_set_up) . In this document I am stuck on Google App Engine set up.  in first point 1) Create a new project from "Checkout Projects from SVN" I am not able to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The command you need is on this page: http://code.google.com/p/sfdc-gae-sso-delegated-auth/source/checkout

Comment: Can you please explain the steps? do I need to install an SVN or not or where do I execute this code?

Comment: you need to install svn, then execute the command given. It'll then go and get the source code for you.  Suggest you look up some basic svn usage. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/ Or you can just download the code directly

Comment: this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900786/how-to-download-checkout-a-project-from-google-code-in-windows

Comment: the svn link given here https://code.google.com/p/sfdc-gae-sso-delegated-auth/source/checkout  is not working correctly is it a problem due to the way I am trying or repositary doesn't exist?

Comment: I can't try it at the moment I'm afraid. Might be an idea to ask a new question on this new problem :)

Comment: Thanks for your help I made it working using http://sfdc-gae-sso-delegated-auth.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/