# Install SVN on Hosting Server

Tags: svn

I am using Visual SVN along with Tortoise. I want to check that if my Hosting server supports SVN ( how can i check it?) and if not present how can i install it there? 
Reason: the reason i'm doing it is that, i want to provide access/ privilege to other persons in our coding for reviews. 
Help Needed !

P.S- I also need to inform that i have got Windows Server on my Hosting

Comment: Is your hosting server a Linux machine, for which distribution? Try to install the package providing `svn`; for Debian that is `subversion`

Comment: @Basile:No it is based on Windows. Is it possible to do it there? Any hopes?

Comment: I know nothing about Windows, I never used it. What is the reason for using Windows, while Unix systems are so good for hosting services?

Comment: You will need to ask your hosting provider.

Comment: Another thing that i wanna know is that: r Visual SVN and Tortoise complement to each other or Substitutes. I mean that will both of them needs to be installed or just one of them will do. I'm confused with this a bit :(

Comment: You can use svn thru a command line, or e.g. thru the `emacs` editor (at least on Linux).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better contact your hosting provider. Check (features) if your hosting package includes svn hosting. If they don't provide it you have to either change your hosting provider or use some other available options (free public and private svn servers).

For open source software you can use (just mentioning a few out of numerous hosts):
i. http://code.google.com
ii. http://sourceforge.net/
iii. http://www.codeplex.com/

For private hosting check (just mentioning a few out of numerous hosts)
i. https://www.assembla.com [provides free private for 1 month]
ii. http://unfuddle.com/ [provides free private too]

Comment: There is also http://myversioncontrol.com/ and you could consider using GIT eg http://gitorious.org/ etc....

Comment: Okk, i have reached to http://code.google.com now how to install it there? Struggling a bit with this. F1 F1 F1 !!!

Comment: You need to install an SVN client like tortoise-svn. Have a look on this SO question to get the idea how to use tortoise-svn for google code: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766/how-do-i-download-code-using-svn-tortoise-from-google-code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766/how-do-i-download-code-using-svn-tortoise-from-google-code)

If you prefer command-line I can also tell you how. The procedure is pretty much same.

Comment: @Atique: I need it as simple as possible. I'm  a novice in this. So, what u will find easy will be the best for me.

Comment: Please google yourself to find what's best for you. I can suggest you to visit site like this: http://mzaher.wordpress.com/2009/03/02/how-to-use-svn-with-google-code/ which explains how to use tortoise svn for Google Code with snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to have a dedicated server to have an option to install something different than preconfigured web server. If you need to share your project codebase with your teammates I would recommend to look for a hosted SVN or Git repository.

There are many providers offering different subscriptions including free plans. Check out http://svnrating.com/ where you can compare various offers.