# Downloading source code from code.google.com

Tags: android

I found this very interesting android application on the internet,  called mytracks. I would like to download its source code from code.google.com. I read a few forums on the net, they suggested downloading svn1.3 from the following link http://downloadsvn.codeplex.com/.  But when I try downloading the source code,  it gives me the following error-

Failed to download: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

Please help.

Comment: What platform are you running? I'd suggest downloading a full svn client such as http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/  
  
EDIT: according to http://code.google.com/p/mytracks/source/checkout this project uses mercurial not SVN, so that would be why you are having trouble. Try finding a mercurial client instead. (http://mercurial.selenic.com/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I download code using SVN/Tortoise from Google Code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766/how-do-i-download-code-using-svn-tortoise-from-google-code)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the MyTracks Source page:

http://code.google.com/p/mytracks/source/checkout

and the associated Mercurial FAQ:

http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/MercurialFAQ#Why_should_I_create_a_server-side_clone?

Comment: I just downloaded the mercurial client from the following link, mercurial.selenic.com. Then in a folder, where I want to download my source, I right clicked and went to clone repository and added the following link in the source
http://code.google.com/p/mytracks/source/checkout

but it is again giving an error 'URLError: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed' 

And please do bear with me, I am quite new to all this, I may go around asking silly questions, but isn't that with all of us when we start. So, I am am doing something wrong please hep me out.

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but are you using a proxy server?  Sometimes this can interfere.

Comment: I changed my proxy settings to noproxy, but still i'm getting an error, this time its very different though.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to download it after a few trials.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about using svn1.3, but I always have used [Tortoise Hg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/). You can go the folder that you would like to check out the source code to, right click, and select Tortoise Hg -> Clone.  From there you would copy in the URL  `https://code.google.com/p/mytracks/`  and it should all download.  I just did it, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: If you have downloaded the source, can you please email it to me on
salmanak@iitk.ac.in. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to download it after a few trials.

Comment: Great! I'm glad.  If this worked for you, can you please select it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the download error, it could be attributed to your browser settings, you may want to adjust the security settings. I usually have two browsers, one with strict settings and one without.

Comment: could there be a problem with my proxy settings? Should I set it to noproxy?

Comment: Yes, set it to No Proxy and retry the download.

Comment: I did that,,  now i am etting a very weird error, its too long to be posted in a comment, so i'm posting it in my original question.

Comment: its not even getting pasted in the main question, there is some problem with the formating.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to download it after a few trials.