# Download a file from an SVN repository

Tags: svn, download

I need to download the files at https://biosignalgroup.repositoryhosting.com/svn/biosignalgroup_wclust/ onto my Windows system.

I installed svn for Windows, and tried the command:

```
svn checkout https://biosignalgroup.repositoryhosting.com/svn/biosignalgroup_wclust/
```

It asked for authentication and the log lists a few files but I cannot find them on my pc. Please help.

I do not need to work with svn after this, I just need to download all the files onto my system in one go instead of right click and saving each of them.

Comment: Without credentials for that repository, you can't do anything (installing TortoiseSVN isn't going to help you). Talk to whomever told you that you need to get those files.

Comment: Found this question answered here based on the TortoiseSVN lead.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766/how-do-i-download-code-using-svn-tortoise-from-google-code . I had access to the folder, I just didn't know how to download it. This worked, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `svn checkout [repo-url] [destination]`

Comment: If you need just to **download** and you don't need to track changes you can use `svn export` command instead of `svn checkout`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @bahrep mentioned, if you don't need to work with svn in the future you want an `svn export` which will not create a working copy and it's associated files

Before you do the export, check to see if the URL is correct... in a standard svn repository there would be three folders under `https://biosignalgroup.repositoryhosting.com/svn/biosignalgroup_wclust`

To check that do an
`svn list https://biosignalgroup.repositoryhosting.com/svn/biosignalgroup_wclust`
If you see `branches` `tags` and `trunk`, you're going to need more info, ask whoever gave you the URL if you want the trunk, a certain branch or tag.

Once you sort which branch, tag or trunk you want,from a commandline:

```
svn export https://biosignalgroup.repositoryhosting.com/svn/biosignalgroup_wclust biosignalgroup_wclust
```

Will export the files to a directory named `biosignalgroup_wclust` in whatever directory you where in.