# TortoiseSVN: "Operation failed"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Hi all I am new to TortoiseSVN and I am unable to access `svn` repository. I have installed TortosiseSVN and created a new empty folder and I clicked on `SVN Checkout` and I pasted the URL: `svn://dvdwalt@svn.code.sf.net/p/radiusdesk/code/trunk/rd` in the dialog box and clicked "OK" (AS its mentioned in in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766/how-do-i-download-code-using-svn-tortoise-from-google-code)).
But I am getting below mentioned errors and its showing that *"operation failed"*.

```
Error   Unable to connect to a repository at URL
Error   'svn://dvdwalt@svn.code.sf.net/p/radiusdesk/code/trunk'
Error   Can't connect to host 'svn.code.sf.net': A connection attempt failed because 
Error   the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or Error   established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

I just want to know where I am doing mistake and cant I get access to those repository via TortoiseSVN tool.

Answer (score 1):

`svn checkout svn://dvdwalt@svn.code.sf.net/p/radiusdesk/code/trunk` works perfectly for me. If you are behind a proxy, configure its settings in [TortoiseSVN | Settings | Network](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-network). If you are behind a firewall, make sure that port 3690 is open (the port is usually used for [`svnserve`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/svnserve/)).