# Lockbox 3 - Delphi 7 - SHA-256

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, sha256, lockbox-3

I am trying to use Lockbox 3.6.3 in Delphi 7. Specifically, I want to use the TSHA2 class.

However, when I try to compile a Delphi 7 project that uses the TSHA2 class i get various compilation errors.

The TPLB3.IntegerUtils unit generates errors in functions inside an IntegerUtils_Pascal conditional defines. There are four functions that are declared with an inline directive that is not valid for Delphi 7.

The TPLB3.Common.inc file uses $IF and $IFEND that are not valid in Delphi 7.

I am under the impression that Lockbox 3.6.3 can be compiled using Delphi 7. Is I could not find any documentation that listed anything specific that needed to be done in order to compile with Delphi 7.

The only class I need in Delphi 7 is the TSHA2 class using the SHA_256 TSHA2FamiliyMember.

Any information on how to compile the Lockbox 3.6.3 classes in a Delphi 7 project would be appreciated.

Comment: try version 3.6.0 - it was said to be tested in Delphi 7 http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/HomePage

Comment: You can download 3.6.0 directly from: https://tplockbox.googlecode.com/svn/tags/LB%203.6.0.0%2010-Nov-2014/  See here how to easily download from googlecode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766/how-do-i-download-code-using-svn-tortoise-from-google-code

Comment: `Support for {$IF}{$ELSE} compiler directives` was introduced in Delphi 6, so I'm pretty sure D7 supports it. Here's the github version for D7: https://github.com/SeanBDurkin/tplockbox/tree/romankassebaum-fork-267

Comment: A while ago I also needed SHA2 on Delphi 7 and couldn't find any (suitably licensed) option, so made my own: http://yoy.be/md5.html